# What is the signature for Java's ByteArray?

Tags: java, kotlin, java-native-interface

I'm trying to call `onEventChannel` through C++ over JNI:

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity(){
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        private fun onEventChannel(b: ByteArray): Int {
            Log.d(TAG, "onEventChannel");
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

I tried `(Ljava/lang/byte;)I` and `(Ljava/lang/ByteArray;)I` for the `onEventChannel` but none of them work.

What is the signature for java's `ByteArray`?

Comment: Try using `[B`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I don't know Flutter, and haven't used JNI.)

There's no such class as `java.lang.byte`<sup>*</sup>, nor `java.lang.ByteArray`.

On Kotlin/JVM, [ByteArray](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-byte-array/) compiles down to a simple primitive array — what would be called `byte[]` in Java.

And that has the JVM descriptor `[B`.  (You can see this by printing `ByteArray(0).toString()`, which starts with `[B` (before the `@` and hash code).  The gory details are in the [JVM Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html).)

So I'd suggest trying `[B`!

---

(* There *is* [java.lang.Byte](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html), but that's the primitive wrapper class used for boxing bytes.)

Comment: "On Kotlin/JVM, ByteArray compiles down to a simple primitive array". Do you mean that when passing through JNI, then ByteArray is accepted as jbytearray? Or in other words, writing ByteArray in Kotlin and then passing it into a context where byte[] is expected does work?

Comment: @mavavilj The Kotlin language has a `ByteArray` class. But the end product of the Kotlin/JVM compiler is Java bytecode — and that bytecode has no knowledge of `ByteArray`; when Kotlin source code mentions `ByteArray`, the generated bytecode contains a simple primitive `byte[]` array instead. So that's all JNI &c will see. You can pass it to anything expecting a `byte[]` array, because at runtime it _is_ a `byte[]` array.